# VS 2008 Team System crash on opening solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

VS 2008 crashes whilst opening a solution file when it reaches the stage of "Loading project files 'Solution Items'".

Is there any way of either stopping the virtual folder of solution items from opening or a workaround for this? The solution is coming from TFS 2005 and source control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could try is removing the .suo file of your solution. This files contains your personal settings and can get corrupted sometimes. It also contains which documents where open when you exited, so removing this file also clears that list.

Answer (score 0):

.sln (and .csproj) files are just text files. So you could open the solution fle in a text editor and remove the entry for the offending project or item.

Comment: Removing the entry for the item just causes its predecessor to fail. If I remove all of them, then it doesn't open the whole project. Could it be something to do with the fact that the "Solution Items" guid isn't repeated later in the .sln file?

Comment: I assume your solution consists of a number of projects, and from what you've said above it looks like it's one of these failing to load. Can you open the relevant project file in a text editor, and remove the reference to the offending 'solution items'?

Comment: The reference only exists in the FullBuild.sln file. (at least according to windows search). When i remove that reference it causes the crash to happen at a point before the place it was referenced

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new solution and adding the projects from the old solution into it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with crashing Visual Studio too. Mine went away when I reset window positions.

I'm not sure that you crash is like that, though.